# The custom Logger is giving error when call from another project in solution

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, log4net-appender

I have created a class for customLogger to log the data and made a change in the web.config file for the same

```
<log4net>
    <root>
      <level value="ALL"/>
      <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
      <appender-ref ref="MultiPhaseCreateOrderMainLogger"/>
      <appender-ref ref="CustAppender" />

    </root>

   <appender name="CustAppender" type="getClient.CustomAppender.CustAppender">
      <threshold value="ERROR" />
    </appender>
</log4net>
```

In the class where  I need to do the logs, I have added the following code.

```
        private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("CustAppender");

            log.Error("something");
```

This code is working fine when I am making the request using postman but when I am running this code using another project from solution for writing the test cases. It is not working

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: Are you sure your `type` in configuration is correct? If you are referencing logger from different library, you have to use something like this: `type="Your.Namespace.And.ClassName, YourDllLibraryName"`. Also, you need this section in your test project.

Comment: @Peska Yes, the type is correct. and I tried using this  type="Your.Namespace.And.ClassName, YourDllLibraryName" but didn't work